# Is it possible to configure xorg to ignore mouse events on certain windows

Tags: unix, x11, xlib, xorg

Is it possible to configure xorg to ignore mouse events on certain windows?

I mean make certain window visible to user, but transparent to the mouse events, e.g. if there is some window always on top, can I somehow click through it.

Maybe there is some extentions for xorg server or native options or window manager to "hide" certain window from it (by `wm_class` or title)?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this specific question, but maybe if you explain what you're trying to implement (in a higher level) we can suggest you to do something else instead of this event-ignoring-window. Maybe this can be implemented with a mouse grab?

Comment: I'm trying to implement a transparent window (notification window for example) that will appears on top in some region on screen without grabbing mouse events in this region. Just to allow user see the notification or some other data and still work with other windows below the notification window. I believe I can use such thing for several purposes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [pygtk window with box that ignores all X(mouse)events (passes them through)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046440/pygtk-window-with-box-that-ignores-all-xmouseevents-passes-them-through)