# PyQt window transparent for user actions?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, transparency, x11, mask

I'm looking for a way to make a toplevel window transparent for mouse clicks and keyboard events. So basically it has to be only *visible* for the user, not interfere with what else happens on the desktop.  (will be transparent) I looked at various options like setting a mask, but that also makes the window disappear where the mask is set. So what I need is a mask, only for user actions, not for visibility.

I got this to work in PyGtk using  input_shape_combine_mask()
which accesses x11 shape extensions. I looked for a similar function in PyQt but couldn't find it. In other posts I find it has been done in PyQt under windows. But x11 I couldn't find yet. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pygtk window with box that ignores all X(mouse)events (passes them through)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9046440/pygtk-window-with-box-that-ignores-all-xmouseevents-passes-them-through)

Comment: Thnx yes I know it can be done with X11 toolkit, and also there are PyGtk bindigs for those. But I dont feel like switching to PyGtk or C just for this functionality...